# How to get Spotify playlist tracks and parse the JSON?

Tags: json, spotify

I am trying to figure out how to parse the JSON data that I am getting from the Spotify API. I am using this node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-js to get Spotify playlist tracks.

I am using this to GET my json (see what I did there)

```
export class HomePage {
spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi;

constructor() {}
}
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
spotifyApi.setAccessToken('Spotify OAuth Token');
spotifyApi.getPlaylistTracks('37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF')
.then(function(data) {
console.log('Playlist Tracks', data);
}, function(err) {
console.error(err);



var prev = null;

function onUserInput(queryTerm) {

// abort previous request, if any
if (prev !== null) {
prev.abort();
}

// store the current promise in case we need to abort it
prev = spotifyApi.searchTracks(queryTerm, {limit: 5});
prev.then(function(data) {

// clean the promise so it doesn't call abort
prev = null;

// ...render list of search results...

}, function(err) {
console.error(err);
});
}
```

This returns a JSON file but for some reason (probably my mistake) when I use `JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.name)` it doesn't work (I know I am doing something wrong here but I don't know how to fix it). Thanks in advance :**{**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the tracks from the url you have to do this `data.tracks.track[0]` replace 0 with the needed tracks.

Comment: hey @Mark, with the last.fm api I am not able to get the images related to the track, so I am thinking to use some other api. How would you think would be the best way approach the problem?

Comment: try ```data.tracks.track[0].image[0].text``` and try to put that text in an image tag for the html. Also have you seen your JSON? The image is there

Comment: No the image it self dosen't work. (this is one of the image links - "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png"

Comment: Oh, so I think you try to find another api and check first if your needed functionalities can be accommodated. But be sure to check if your current api have alternatives regarding to getting an image.